# Calculate Difference between months

Tags: powerbi, dax

Dears,

I have a fact table with Sales Values and Date dimension. Fact table contains cumulative values, for example: January: 1100, February: 1100+1000, March: 1100+1000+1200 etc.

I want to add measure which returns values for seperate months. For example: in Jan 1100, in Feb 1000, in March 1200. I was trying to use this code:

```
SUM('SALES'[SALES VALUE])-CALCULATE(SUM('SALES'[SALES VALUE]),PREVIOUSMONTH('DATE'[DATE])
```

but it still returns invalid value.

Below you find Excel with result in column D which I want to receive.

[image]

Comment: Have you got a proper Calendar/Date table setup, ie 1/9/2020 as the date not 20200901?

Comment: I also meant to say that your formula works for me, with some quick dummy data I threw together and a proper Calendar table

Comment: Yes, I have Date dimension with date

Comment: Can you put up a screenshot of your data model, relationships, matrix/visualisation with the incorrect result?

Answer (score 0):

Create a column as below :

```
CurrentMonthSales = 
var prev_month =
                CALCULATE(SUM(Sales[Sales Value]),FILTER(Sales,EARLIER(Sales[Date]) = NEXTMONTH(Sales[Date])))
    return
                Sales[Sales Value] - prev_month
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work for me :( I need to create measure, not calculated column

Comment: Ok, I am not sure about how to create a measure for this as of now,  but creating a column works for me. Will it make a huge impact if you create a column instead of a measure? Added a screenshot for reference.

Comment: @Sanchit Sood I think they must have an issue with their data model setup or they’re doing something like using the date column from their Sales table in their visual not from the Calendar table. The formula worked fine for me

Comment: @Ben Yeah possible